# Unable to write text to a .txt file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows forms application, that is supposed to store its config data on a file called `config.txt`. I have this code, which runs when the form is initialized. Here is the function:

```
string folderPath = @‘C:\Users\Public\Periodic_Clock\’;
string filePath = @‘C:\Users\Public\Periodic_Clock\config.txt’;

public Form1()
{

   InitializeComponent();
   once = 0;
   if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
   {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
   }

   if (!File.Exists(filePath))
   {
      new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
      File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Alarm" + Environment.NewLine + "Alarm Ringing!" + Environment.NewLine + 1);
   }
   else
   {

   }
   notificationTitle = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(0).Take(1).First();
   notificationText = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1).Take(1).First();
}
```

Pretty much, I have an app that sends a notification when a timer goes off. I want to use this config file to store a custom title, text and notification type for the notification. (so that the user can customize what the notification looks like) My intention with this was to have the first line as the notification title, second line as the text, and the third line as a number from 0 - 3, to store the type of notification (info, error, etc.)

I can not manage to get the program to write anything to the text file. It creates it, but it seems to completely skip the part where I use `File.WriteAllText()`. I used other methods like `StreamWriter`, but nothing was written to the text document. The code right now skips the `WriteAllText` part and creates an error at `File.ReadLines`, which just tells me that the sequence contains no elements. What's the problem here? How do I fix it?

Comment: Remove the FileStream construction. Also, is this the actual code or do you have a try/catch block in your code as well?

Comment: Why would you open the file and read all lines twice?

Comment: You have simply misunderstood the use of File.WriteAllText, and also the other calls. Read the documentation. I suggest you use File.WriteAllLines and File.ReadAllLines, and no other calls. If using FileStream, you should use "using (..." and so on.

Comment: You ask what the problem is, so I can tell you that your `new FileStream` will open the file for writing, but then `WriteAllText` will also try to do the same. You can't have two simultaneous writes going on. Also, you mention an error, but give no details.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, I ended up with this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    once = 0;
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }
    try
    {
        FileStream config = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        config.Close();
        StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        writetext.Write("Alarm");
        writetext.WriteLine();
        writetext.Write("Alarm Ringing!");
        writetext.WriteLine();
        writetext.Write("1");                
        writetext.Close();

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!");
    }
    notificationTitle = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(0).Take(1).First();
    notificationText = File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(1).Take(1).First();
}
```